# Roughly when did humans become attentive to their own look for external gratification

Tags: evolution, human-nature, self-cognition

I read that there are objects that were used as mirrors dating back to 8000BCE. If so, it’s clear that humans needed a quality view of themselves at the very least to see what they looked like.

Is there an understood timeframe for when humans wanted their external look to affect those around them; for intimidation, affection, respect, etc?

Like when did we go from a pack of empty headed scavengers to wanting some sort of social gratification based on the way we look?

Comment: I have no idea, but I suspect it goes along with self-awareness. Magpies can pass the mirror test, and magpies like to decorate. This might be a better question for anthropologists or biologists than for philosophy.